# docker build shows: failed sandbox add: failed to set gateway while updating gateway: invalid argument

Tags: docker

I am running docker on a linux system.

The linux uname -a shows: Linux TENCENT64.site 3.10.94-1-tlinux2-0036.tl2

The docker version is: 1.8.3

when I try to build a image, docker return the error message: failed sandbox add: failed to set gateway while updating gateway: invalid argument

My Dockerfile is:

```
# centos 7

FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER a b


# make work dirs
RUN mkdir /workspace


# add passport files
COPY ./output.tar.gz /workspace/


# add start script
COPY ./resources/start.sh /workspace/


EXPOSE 22
EXPOSE 8082

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

the full error message is:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.284 MB
Step 0 : FROM centos:7
 ---> eeb3a076a0be
Step 1 : MAINTAINER AlphaCloud wangziyi <wangziyi@didichuxing.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dc3d3f638d8d
Step 2 : RUN mkdir /workspace
 ---> Running in 53a34c6d1731
failed sandbox add: failed to set gateway while updating gateway: invalid argument
```

My docker process is:

```
/usr/bin/docker daemon --ip-forward=false --iptables=false --insecure-registry=10.10.10.39
```

help me

Comment: I hope this may help you https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14732

Comment: Hi @Viswesn. Thanks for your answer, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we read some source code of docker, this error is because docker can't find a gateway to access network. our kernel is cut some network models, so we have to run docker in host network mode.

add `--bridge=none` to your docker daemon start command.

the full start command is `docker daemon --bridge=none --ip-forward=false --iptables=false`

but, there is some effect on `docker build`

you can't build image using like yum or else network needed way.

detail see: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22064